# VB.Net thread seems to be running twice giving file access problems

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, file-io

I have some very basic code that takes a list of strings and a new thread is created per string.

The thread then writes a file named with the string so should be unique but I get access violations.

I try the debugger option in VS 2010 and it doesn't give me the file access problems when I step through but it writes two lines per loop so I am assuming it still has a problem with running the thread twice

Code to call the thread:

```
For Each x In x_list
  Dim trd as new Thread(DirectCast(Sub() tp(x), ThreadStart))
Next
```

Code for thread:

```
Private Sub tp(ByVal x_in As String)
  Dim res_file As New StreamWriter("C:\result_" + x_in + ".txt", True)
  For i = 1 to 5
    res_file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString)
  Next
  res_file.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're introducing an unnecessary [Lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) here:

```
Sub() tp(x)
```

And then you're falling foul of the same well known issue from C# - that what you're capturing is the *variable* that keeps changing until it's set to the last value in the loop.<sup>1</sup>

Try instead just:

```
For Each x In x_list
  Dim trd as new Thread(DirectCast(tp, ParameterizedThreadStart))
  trd.Start(x)
  'TODO - Does trd get stored anywhere?
Next
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See e.g. [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) which discusses how there's a change for C#5, but I don't think there's a corresponding change for VB.Net.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer a badly formatted question! I was able to solve the orignal code with the link provided but I ran into some problems with the simpler parameterizedthread solution, 'Argument not specified for parameter x_in of private sub....'